# Add searchbox to a custom map javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I'm new to google maps and geolocation, and I'm trying to add a searchbox to this map, which already has a marker with the user's current location on it. I've tried many different things, but when the button to load the map is clicked, nothing happens. Can anyone help? Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
       html, body, #mapholder {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
       }

       .controls {
        margin-top: 16px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 32px;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
       }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        width: 400px;
        font-family: Times;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
       }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
        margin-left: -1px;
        padding-left: 14px;  /* Regular padding-left + 1. */
        width: 401px;
      }

      .pac-container {
        font-family: Times;
      }

      #type-selector {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
       }

       #type-selector label {
       font-family: Times;
       font-size: 13px;
       font-weight: 300;
      }
}    </style>
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script>

     var ref_latitude = "";
        var ref_longitude = "";
        var boundary_latitude = "";
        var boundary_longitude = "";



function initialize() {

  var markers = [];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapholder’), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
       new google.maps.LatLng(36.983, -122.0031),
       new google.maps.LatLng(36.9, -122.003));
 map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
   var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
       document.getElementById('pac-input'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input));

  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
     for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }


    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };


      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
         position: place.geometry.location
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  // [END region_getplaces]

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
  // current map's viewport.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
   });
 }


var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
 }

 function showPosition(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
    latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
    mapholder = document.getElementById('mapholder')
    mapholder.style.height = '250px';
    mapholder.style.width = '500px';

    var myOptions = {
    center:latlon,zoom:14,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl:false,
    navigationControlOptions:{style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL}
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapholder"), myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:latlon,map:map,title:"You are here!"});
}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
         case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
<style>
  #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">    
<button onclick="getLocation()">Find me!</button>

<div id="mapholder"></div>



  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code (the javascript console indicates: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`), the ’ doesn't close the string for 'mapholder' (it doesn't match a single quote).

```
function initialize() {

  var markers = [];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapholder’), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
```

should be:

```
function initialize() {

  var markers = [];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapholder'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
```

working code snippet:

```js
var ref_latitude = "";
var ref_longitude = "";
var boundary_latitude = "";
var boundary_longitude = "";

function initialize() {

  var markers = [];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapholder'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(36.983, -122.0031),
    new google.maps.LatLng(36.9, -122.003));
  map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (input));

  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }


    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };


      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  // [END region_getplaces]

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
  // current map's viewport.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#mapholder {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.controls {
  margin-top: 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  width: 400px;
  font-family: Times;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
  margin-left: -1px;
  padding-left: 14px;
  /* Regular padding-left + 1. */
  width: 401px;
}
.pac-container {
  font-family: Times;
}
#type-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}
#type-selector label {
  font-family: Times;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places"></script>
<div id="mapholder" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<input id="pac-input" />
```

Comment: when the map shows the user's current location the search box disappears. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Troubleshooting